# How to check if LOGON USER already answered

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, if-statement, data-retrieval

In my code I have this

```
<h2> Address Book</h2> <br />
    <table>
    <tr><td><b>User:</b></td><td><asp:Label ID="useren" runat="server"></asp:Label></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><b>Business:</b></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="business" runat="server" MaxLength="13"></asp:TextBox> (Example: 234925xxx)</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Business 2:</b></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="business2" runat="server" MaxLength="13"></asp:TextBox> (Example: xxxx)</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Mobile:</b></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="mobile" runat="server" MaxLength="13"></asp:TextBox> (Example: 9xxxxxxxx)</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="cmdSave_Click2" /></td><td></td></tr>
    </table
```

In my code behind this to retrieve the logon user

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    useren.Text = "[" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "]";
}
```

This to storage the text box and the logon user into the database

```
protected void cmdSave_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sFilePath = Server.MapPath("Database3.accdb");
    OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sFilePath + ";Persist Security Info=False;");
    string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO Worker(Business,Business2,Mobile,username) VALUES (@Business,@Business2,@Mobile,@useren)";
    using (Conn)
    {
        Conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertCmd, Conn);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Business", business.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Business2", business2.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", mobile.Text);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useren", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name); 
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        Label1.Text = "Saved Successfull!";
        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
}
```

How can I check if the logon user already answered? My goal is if the logon user already exist em Access database retrieve his data 
or how can I make when I execute the button onclick="cmdSave_Click2" if the user exist retrive an label warning up "the user already answered" for example

Comment: [Please learn about formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

Give an attempt in this way. It may give you a idea to solve the issue.

```
protected void cmdSave_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string sFilePath = Server.MapPath("Database3.accdb");
  OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sFilePath + ";Persist Security Info=False;");
  con.Open();
  OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Select count(*) from Worker where username = '"+HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name+"'",con);
  int total = (Int32)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
  if(total==0)
  {
   OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sFilePath + ";Persist Security Info=False;");
  string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO Worker(Business,Business2,Mobile,username) VALUES (@Business,@Business2,@Mobile,@useren)";
  using (Conn)
  {
    Conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertCmd, Conn);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Business", business.Text);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Business2", business2.Text);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", mobile.Text);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useren", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name); 
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    Label1.Text = "Saved Successfull!";
    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    Conn.Close();
  }
  }
  else
  {
       Label1.Text = "Existing user";
  }
  con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Give me error [[Error 1 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ]]

Comment: Check my answer now. I have updated it as per you want. Mark it as answer if it resolves your issue.

Comment: How can I change the connection's state? (yes i'm learning)
It give me error: "*ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.*"

Comment: i switch order " int total = (Int32)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
  con.Open(); " but it mess up with my css style :/ (and when i load the program again doesn't detect me and allows me to field the text box again.
the ideia was if the logon user already exist in database display that

Comment: the idea is *IF* username already exist in database retrieve data from database *ELSE* the questions will appear to field the text box...
have no idea how do that, but seems @gkrishy code only display the user already exist it means i field the text box then if there's data in ACCESS Label1.Text = "Existing user"; or else Label1.Text = "Saved Successfull!" but in either way i need field the textbox

Comment: @KikoFHM For that error which u mentioned in ur comment, you remove con.open and con.close , and try again.

Comment: i remove **con.Open(); and con.Close();** @gkrishy but still giving error about *executescalar* but also mess up with my CSS Style (don't know why :/ but all my fonts family, font size it's mess up) but for I understand of your code only will say the user exist **after** I click "save" there's another way to alert me the user already exist **before** I start field the text box?

Comment: @KikoFHM Check my answer now. I have placed con.Open in other place. And Yeah you can do that with the help of Page load. Before entering into textbox, the page is having the username right ?

Comment: ok @gkrishy  at last stop giving error  :) (still find out why the page style became a mess). about the page, I have this `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    useren.Text = "[" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "]";
}` to display the user in one label. Below that the questions(textbox) to field. My goal (would make possible) was detect the username in access database and if true display the storage data if false show the questions to answered.

Comment: @KikoFHM What you saying is different question!. That's not related to this question.If it resolves your issue, make it as correct answer. And ask your style sheet  error in other question.

Comment: it's not what I pretend (show if username already exist/answered in database before answered the field text) . But i will accept @gkrishy answered because for all matters doesn't show me any code error.