# verify username existence in access database when page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, pageload

i have a label to identify windows login user.

```
<table>
        <tr><td><b>Utilizador:</b></td><td><asp:Label ID="username" runat="server"></asp:Label></td></tr>
</table>
```

my code behind when page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    username.Text = "[" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "]"; 
}
```

how can warn (message.box or label) user that he already exist in access database?

(i already have the insert into code)

Comment: Hope I answered already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406841/how-to-check-if-logon-user-already-answered/31407574#31407574)

Comment: You want to show the warning message in Message box instead of showing in label ?

Comment: @gkrishy in other post the text only appears after i click the button... but the purpose is before field the text.box .... is open the page and if the username already answerd message that otherwise field the table

Comment: @KikoFHM That last comment is extremely difficult to read or understand.  Could you attempt to clarify please?

Comment: @Newd i have a table to user answer but i want say a message if that specific user already answered.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply adding a label or a validator to display the message that the user already exists. In the code behind, you can simply make the message visible when the user already exists. Something like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Utilizador:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="username" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="userAlreadyExistsRow" runat="server">
    <td colspan="2">
      <asp:Label ID="userAlreadyExistsLbl" runat="server" 
         Text="This user exists already" </asp:Label>
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    username.Text = "[" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "]"; 

    var userAlreadyExists = true; // replace by appropriate condition
    userAlreadyExistsRow.Visible = userAlreadyExists;
}
```

Comment: your solution was the closest i can get so far, but even so... not what i pretend =( when i debbug the label says "This user exists already" but i delete my username from database and i still have the message "This user exists already" :/

Comment: You must query the database in Page_Load to  and set the message row to be visible if the user is found.

Comment: hmm can you help me? how can i do that?